# $2\times2$ matrix powers are equal to identity

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that if a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ with whole number elements satisfies $A^n=I$ for some integer $n$, then $A^{12}=I$.

Comment: I mean that the entries of the matrices are integers, sorry

Comment: I have tried to find a general formula for the $n-$th matrix power with no success yet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ be the complex eigenvalues of $A$. If $A^n=I$ for some integer $n$, then $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are roots of unity. On the other hand, they are also roots of a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Therefore the problem amounts to determining which roots of unity can lie in a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. It turns out that the $n$th roots of unity lie in a quadratic extension precisely when $n=1,2,3,4$, and $6$. Since these are all divisors of $12$, it follows that in all these cases $A^{12}=I$.

Comment: Just a remark: the statement about the $n$-th roots of unity follows from solving $\varphi(n) = 2$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's function.

Comment: $\phi(n)\leq 2$ actually, but yes.

Comment: Oh, sure, thanks for the correction.