# If $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb Z$ such that $A^{n}=I$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, then $A^{12}=I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

> If $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb Z$ such that $A^{n}=I$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, then show that $A^{12}=I$.

My effort: The natural projection $\pi: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ will induce a ring homomorphism $\Pi: M_2(\mathbb Z)\to M_2(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$. Since $\Pi$ maps $1$ to $1$, it will induce a surjection from the group $GL_2(\mathbb Z)$ to $GL_2(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$ with kernel $=(M_2(2\mathbb Z)+I)\cap GL_2(\mathbb Z)$. Now $\Pi(A^n)=I$ implies that $\Pi(A)\in GL_2(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$. Since $|GL_2(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)|=6$, $A^6 \in (M_2(2\mathbb Z)+I)\cap GL_2(\mathbb Z)$.

> How can I complete from here ?

Comment: $\Pi(2I)=0$, but $2I \notin GL_2(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: I see. Thanks.${}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158209

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066268